# How to create a html site with menu staying on top and content transitioning side ways?

Tags: html

This is the site that is close to what I want but should move side ways, http://www.culturalsolutions.co.uk/ .
I don't even know what to search for, online about a site like this.
But i want to make a site with a menu always on top like this and having the content go side ways instead. Also is it possible to embed a blog to the body area so its all on one single page? I just don't want users to go from one page to another, i like those flash site transition but they are not ipad friendly :<

Answer (score 2):

You can use js and CSS

**Demo** : http://jsmenu.com/demo/jquerymenu/nagging-menu-with-css3-and-jquery/index.html

**Download** : http://jsmenu.com/download/jquerymenu/nagging-menu-with-css3-and-jquery.zip

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with css `position:fixed;top:30px;z-index:1000;`, so it always stays top

Here Z-Index you need to choose max value

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to style the container you want as the fixed element.

```
#navigation {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

And remove vertical scroll with:

```
body {
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Your content in the body could then have div's with `float: left` to put the flow horizontally.

UPDATE:
On second thought, perhaps it would be better to skip the `overflow-y: hidden` and just use `float: left`. And you need to put a width on the div holding your content. See this [tutorial](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/02/useful-tips-to-design-horizontal.html)

Comment: @Andy Y, did you come up with a solution for your problem?